# Are there any browser based webpage designers available?

Tags: web-applications

I've got the task of trying to figure out how to produce a browser based dashboard designer, whereby you would typically add/drag n' drop controls on and then somehow bind them up.  Typical examples to illustrate would be the web page design canvas in visual studio, or even powerpoint and it's storyboarding mode.

I could probably build something up using jquery but I'm trying to find out if there are any pre-existing libraries out there that allow this sort of behaviour - unfortunately it's a really hard thing to get the correct search terms on. I've only managed to find examples for building customer facing sites for cafes and the like which isn't what I want - we're more chart focused.

Has anyone come across javascript libraries that allow this sort of behaviour, open source or otherwise so I can examine them and weigh up their relative merits?

Examples that I've seen that I don't think are right (because they're all based on templates) would be things like weebly and breezi

Comment: Have you already looked at [juice](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Nope, taking a look now. For anyone else I'm essentially trying to find something configurable by and end user that gives a much slicker/custom user experience than tools such as SharePoint.

Comment: LMGTFY http://dzineblog.com/2012/07/30-browser-based-apps-for-web-designers-developers.html

Comment: @kadumel: None of the items in that list are helpful or address my question... I've already come across such pages that aren't helpful because googling "drag drop browser webpage builder" for example returns a lot of useless examples.

Comment: @Ian it's still pretty funny, none the less.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873779/a-newbiecareer-guidence-where-to-start-my-career) doesn't belong to [programmers.se] either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this search query:

https://www.google.com/search?q=web-based+dashboard+design

It brings up several results that look promising.

- [NetCharts](http://www.visualmining.com/nc-designer/)
- [Solver](http://www.solverusa.com/products/product-suite/dashboards/)
- [Jaspersoft](https://www.jaspersoft.com/dashboards)

These all seem to be commercial applications, so hopefully you are not looking for a "free" version, although NetCharts does offer a 7-day trial, I think. We have used Dundas Charts in the past and although there is a lot of back-end configurability with that package, I'm not particularly thrilled with them.